# Is it possible to do live events in YUI, similar to jQuery's live events?

Tags: yui, jquery

It doesn't currently seem as though there is a way to do live events in YUI similar to jQuery: http://api.jquery.com/live/

It sure would be nice if something like:

```
function handleClick(e) {
    // click!
}

YUI().use('node-base', function(Y) {
    Y.on("click", handleClick, ".foo");
});
```

caused `handleClick` to be fired when a node with the "foo" class was clicked on after being  dynamically added to the DOM *and* sometime after the `Y.on` was evaluated. I feel like live events are one of jQuery's killer features that YUI lacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use YUI3's support for [event delegation](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/3/api/YUI.html#method_delegate) to accomplish the same thing.

```
YUI().use("node", "event", function(Y) {
    Y.delegate("click", function() {
        //click!
    }, Y.config.win, ".foo");
});
```

I think attaching that to the window is ok, you might need to attach it to the body instead.

Use `Y.one("body")` instead of `Y.config.win` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

YUI 2's Event Utility also supports a [`delegate` method](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/event/#delegate).